# Defining an Infinite Matrix

Tags: discrete-mathematics, matrix-equations, infinite-matrices

Hey I am getting ready for my final exam and I'm having trouble figuring out this practice question:

Let X be a random variable that takes values in {0,1,2,3,...}. It is known that:

E(X) = $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k * Pr(X = k)$

Define an infinite matrix and use it to prove that:

E(X) = $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}Pr(X \ge k)$

I am thinking that we would need to add up all sums of columns but I'm not quite sure where to go after that.

Comment: The claim does not hold in general.

Comment: You should change the second equation to $E(X) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} Pr(X \ge k)$

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you start with the corrected version

$E(X) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(X \ge k)$

You can write $Pr(X \ge k)$ as $\sum_{j=k}^\infty P(X =j)$. Now we have

$E(X) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \displaystyle\sum_{j=k}^{\infty} P(X =j)$.

We're free to choose the order of in the summation (think of instead of summing column-wise than row-wise, do the other way around).  So we can write

$E(X) = \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{j} P(X =j)$.  Since the summand is constant wrt $k$ this can be rewritten simply

$E(X) = \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^\infty jP(X = j)$